# Is there a way to setup webpack config to load specific core-js entries

Tags: javascript, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, spread-syntax

DISCLAIMER: I'm not terribly familiar with webpack or babel outside of simple setup, so if the question isn't clear then I apologize and will do my best to offer further clarity.

So, the situation currently is that a coworker updated a bunch of packages recently, babel among them, and babel is no longer transpiling the code properly for .forEach and spread operators in ie11 (specifically when iterating over a node list). The resulting behavior is a bit frustrating; simply put, nothing happens when the page is loaded in those browsers, no console errors, just nothing.

While troubleshooting this, I've been able to get it fixed by adding core-js as a dependency in package.json and adding the following imports to the main.js file:

```
import 'core-js/stable/array/for-each';
import 'core-js/stable/array/from';
import 'core-js/stable/dom-collections';
import 'core-js/stable/object/get-own-property-symbols';
```

The question is, is there a way to get this same result purely through the webpack config? Again, I'm not all that familiar with how to play around in webpack outside of some basic common setup tasks, so I hope I'm phrasing this in a way that makes sense. If not, I'll do my best to correct based on feedback.

Comment: Webpack cannot know which polyfills your bundle needs.

Comment: Am I just phrasing this poorly? Is it more about babel options as defined within the webpack config?

Comment: Can you post what has changed in package.json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this by webpack.
Take a look at the documentation https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#babelpreset-env
You need babel .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
     "@babel/preset-env",
     {
       "useBuiltIns": "usage",
       "corejs": 3
     }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Then you do not need to add dependency in main.js all dependencies are added automatically by core-js

I prepared the code https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs

Comment: Thank you so much, the "usage" and corejs: 3 are exactly what I needed. I was circling that in the docs but just didn't quite have the level of understanding to piece it together.