# Include Polyfill bundle in application

Tags: javascript, webpack, polyfills

I need to support IE with my application, so I decided to use polyfill.io to support ES6 features.
https://polyfill.io/v3/

It gives me an url, but I'm not sure how to actually use it. I'm using webpack, but I couldn't find a solution up to now.

Last try I did was trying to load it with an ajax request

```
//Version 1
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=String.prototype.includes",
  success: Srv.main,
  dataType: 'script',
}).done(() => appStart());

//Version 2
$.getScript("https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=String.prototype.includes", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
 appStart();
});
```

both seem to return the script and in fact it seems to work at first, no error about String.include in appStart. But I get erors in other modules, where I use the methods. So it seems to be not globally available?

I would appreciate some help, maybe one find an even simpler solution with webpack?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using webpack, it would be a lot easier to just use the babel/polyfill package. Here is a link: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

Comment: Use webpack and [core-js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56803032/10424385) Core-js adds only those polyfill that you need nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) in order to polyfill ECMAscript features into your application.

```
npm i core-js
```

```
import 'core-js/stable'; // <- at the top of your entry point

Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]));          // => [1, 2, 3]
[1, [2, 3], [4, [5]]].flat(2);                 // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Promise.resolve(32).then(x => console.log(x)); // => 32
```

**Edit**

If you want to only include what is needed, you can edit your .babelrc file to include the "useBuiltIns" option

```
// .babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": [
        "Last 2 versions",
      ]

      // This option configures how @babel/preset-env handles polyfills. The 'usage' value imports
      // only the specific polyfill module when they are used in each file.
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
    }]
  ],
}
```

Comment: But as far as I know, you have to specify what you want to load (or just load everything like you did). While polyfill.io has the advantage that it checks what browser you are using and gives you exactly what you need. I would still be interested why you recommend core-js over polyfill.io? (and also how to do it with polyfill.io, if you know that)

Comment: Since you are using webpack, you are probably using bable. This means you have a `.babelrc` file defined somewhere. In your .babelrc file you can add the "useBuiltIns" option to give you exactly what you need. I've edited my answer to show the babelrc file.

Comment: I actually don't use babel, at least not as far as I know. I use Typescript with webpack, which does the transpiling. The edit is still helpful, thanks :)